# Testing local server with MAMP/wordpress on mobile device?

Tags: wordpress, localhost, mamp

I am currently developing a wordpress site locally using MAMP PRO, which obviously involves using a local database.

I would like to test this site on my iPhone via a remote link. I have managed to do this by typing the following into my mobile phone URL...

```
192.234.2.32:8888
```

(IP Address : Port number)

The problem is the index page is displayed but with no CSS styling. Then when I click on another page, it says the page cannot be found

It seems it has connected to the server properly, but not to the wordpress database. (at least I think this is the problem)

Does anyone have any information on how to get this working or point me in the right direction? Do you need another application to do this, or can it be done with mamp/IP address etc?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Please, [don't cross-post](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/64068/185667) your question in the network.

Comment: I wouldn't normally, but wasn't sure which one to put it in, as it covers both wordpress and normal local development (not wordpress related)

Answer (score 1):

I prefer to [use DNS](http://quickshiftin.com/blog/2013/08/local-dev-for-mobile/) to deal with local development for mobile. This way you can still use the same IP address for all your local sites, but have a different name for each one ([NameBasedVirtualHosts](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/vhosts/name-based.html))

Answer (score 1):

- In general settings WordPress; Change The WordPress address from
  localhost to the IP address of your desktop pc/mac (URL)
- In the MAMP PRO general tab; Check; via Xip.io (LAN only)and copy that address
- In general settings WordPress Paste the Xip.io addres in Site Address (URL)
- you can acces the mobile devices via;
  http://localhost.IPAddressOfYourLocalComputer.xip.io

screenshot Wordpress
[image]

Answer (score 0):

I've been able to make a LAN + IOS testing scheme work on OS 10.11 without changing Mamp Pro (4.5) default ports, or change the domain settings in WP admin. Here's all the relevant bits:

- In Finder set up root folder inside "sites" folder i.e. `~/sites/MAMP-hosted/yourdomain.com`
- Ensure your mac is using a static IP address, launch Mamp Pro and in the General tab, select that static IP for `yourdomain.com` in the IP address drop down. `localhost` should remain the default: *
- In the `yourdomain.com` > Databases tab, select the database for `yourdomain.com` (localhost doesn't need to be assigned one)
- All remaining General tab settings are default including name resolution, only etc/hosts option checked
- at the bottom, the localhost > document root should point to the "MAMP-hosted" folder, and `yourdomain.com` > document root should point to the `yourdomain.com` folder.

then adjust wp-config to look like this:

```
define('DB_NAME', 'name-of-your-database');

/** MySQL database username */
define('DB_USER', 'root');

/** MySQL database password */
define('DB_PASSWORD', 'root');

/** MySQL hostname */
define('DB_HOST', 'localhost');

define( 'WP_SITEURL', 'http://your-static-IP' );
define( 'WP_HOME', 'http://your-static-IP' );
```

`http://your-static-IP` should bring up the site on any device on your local network, and `http://your-static-IP/wp-login` for admin access.

If you write to the database (publish posts, etc) with wp-admin in that state you may need to do some post migration clean up with a plugin like Velvet Blue to remove that IP address.

I haven't experimented with this particular scheme and MAMP on-board SSL, however it's not difficult to switch back once the site is ready to migrate to its dedicated host.

Answer (score 0):

First you need to enable Mamp Viewer in your Mamp Pro.

[image]

Then you need to install Mamp Viewer on your mobile.

Your Mamp Server and your mobile need to be in the same network.

So you can view your website in your mobile via mamp viewer or mobile browser with your local domain for example test.local.

Answer (score -3):

you can do this by simply editing the hosts file on your mac.

Or use a tool like https://www.macupdate.com/app/mac/40003/hosts

Point all your domains to the IP of the MAMP host computer, and put the mamp web service on port 80.

use www.domain.dev or similar for the domain names.